# remove unix user named postgres after complete uninstallation of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, linux

I'm running MX Linux 21 and recently installed PostgreSQL-13; I wanted postgres to have read, write and execute access to a certain folder therefore I added the unix user `postgres` to the group of owner and granted such accesses to the group. The commands was: `setfacl -R -m u:postgres:rwx myfolder`

Then I uninstalled postgresql from MX package manager completely (i.e., `sudo apt remove postgresql-13`).

I thought the unix user called `postgres` should be gone with the removal of postgresql, it however was not the case. I am still able to do `sudo su postgres` and logged in as the user `postgres`.

I then did `sudo deluser postgres` and it failed with exit code 8, saying there's process still running on `postgres`.

I then did a `ps -ef` and found that `sudo su postgres` is the main process that held up the deletion of user `postgres`. I killed that process in `htop` and ran `sudo deluser postgres` again with success.

But when I checked with `getfacl` to see if the unix user `postgres` has been deleted from the user group, I found this:

```
$ getfacl myfolder
# file: owner
# owner: owner
# group: owner
user::rwx
user:121:rw-
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

that `user:121` is in place of user `postgres`.
Does this mean installing `postgres` is leaving a trace in my system and I can't purge it?
Does this mean installing `postgres` would always make an user `postgres` in my system and if I don't delete it, it'll be there forever?

Comment: "that user:121 is in place of user postgres"

of course it is, because of you did setfacl earlier, and didn't setfacl -x to remove that access back.

Comment: @RabbanKeyak Thanks that's the command I am looking for; like you said, I should really check the man page first. Your comment should be the answer, whenever you are free then.